# Error consuming wsdl web service with c# The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client

I am trying to consume a wsdl web service (java) using C#. I added the service reference and implemented the webmethod call but it is returning following error:
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message:

> There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://services.company.companyname.com.br:methodNameResponse. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 456. 'EndElement' 'methodNameReturn' from namespace 'http://services.company.companyname.com.br' is not expected. Expecting element 'idSomething'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

I already tried lot of things, like limits of sizes, add ip on host file, etc, but no success. Does anyone have an idea?

The code is:

```
var ws = new webService(); //invoked using the service reference
var return = ws.methodName("x", "CAY", "5454545", "XXXX", "xxx", "09/07", "A", 1,
                                               "23/04/2013", "23/04/2013", "15:00", "17:00");
```

The ws.methodName returns the error.

I already tried with request and response objects and got the same error.

I tested yet using web reference. I got a way it does not return me error, but I needed alter the reference file, commenting the following line, above the invoked method:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://dto.services.company.trielo.com.br")]
```

I'm posting the wsdl: `http://177.140.208.200:8998/mdc4web/services/VisitantesSASweb?wsdl`

Comment: Did you notice the “Please see InnerException for more details.” message?

Comment: The InnerException is "Error in line 1 position 456. 'EndElement' 'somethingReturn' from namespace 'ht tp://services.company.companyName.com.br' is not expected. Expecting element 'idSomething'."} and the InnerException message is null.

Comment: Add more info about the error with some codes, tks any help.

Comment: You should not be modifying the Reference.cs file since that is all code gen. Sounds like you removed a namespace on part of the request and now it isn't serializing/deserializing properly. You should put that line back in and try another route.

Comment: @Barrakoda, tks, but I recreated the reference and I am using service reference. That was only a test I did follwing an example I had got.

Comment: Using fiddler I could check that the answer is comming correctly to me, but the error continues: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><incluiAutorizacaoResponse xmlns="http://services.mdc4web.trielo.com.br"><incluiAutorizacaoReturn><idAutorizacao>0</idAutorizacao><lst><lst>48</lst></lst><msg>Ok</msg><status>0</status></incluiAutorizacaoReturn></incluiAutorizacaoResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two possibles problems between the proxy class generated by Visual Studio and service WSDL

Looking the proxy generated file:

First mistake is the namespace parameter at XmlTypeAttribute attribute in RetVisSRV class

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://dto.services.mdc4web.trielo.com.br")]
```

you need to remove the "dto."

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://services.mdc4web.trielo.com.br")]
```

The second point is the elementName parameter at XmlArrayItemAttribute of "lst" array declaration.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item", Namespace="http://services.mdc4web.trielo.com.br", IsNullable=false)]
```

correct to "lst"

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("lst", Namespace="http://services.mdc4web.trielo.com.br", IsNullable=false)]
```

After these changes should work fine.

This namespaces problems are a known issue between AXIS and .NET clients, but I don't why is not yet solved

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2449

Hope this helps

Comment: Tks too much! It is working fine now. I wouldn't believe it was a know issue between AXIS and .NET. We almost got the fiz, removing dto part, but the corret to "lst" not. Tksssss to much.

Answer (score 1):

Between...

> The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 456.
>   'EndElement' 'methodNameReturn' from namespace
>   'http://services.company.companyname.com.br' is not expected. Expecting
>   element 'idSomething'.'. Please see InnerException for more details.

...and...

> The InnerException is "Error in line 1 position 456. 'EndElement'
>   'somethingReturn' from namespace
>   'http://services.company.companyName.com.br' is not expected. Expecting
>   element 'idSomething'."} and the InnerException message is null.

It *sounds* as though the web service's response content violated the schema being used to deserialize it (basically I think what Barrakoda was getting at) -- although it's difficult to be sure without seeing the response content itself and the schema definition (presumbly defined via the namespace reference to http://services.company.companyname.com.br).

Comment: I hope have no problem to post the wsdl: http://177.140.208.200:8998/mdc4web/services/VisitantesSASweb?wsdl

The problem is I'm not onwer of this web service